# main.go:9: use of package str without selector

Tags: go

I have the following in the intepreter of Tour of Go:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/tour/wc"
    str "strings"
)

func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    results := make(map[str]int)
    words := str.Fields(s)
    return map[string]int{"x": 1}
}

//func main() {
//  wc.Test(WordCount)
//}
```

This is based on https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/23

My error is

```
tmp/sandbox169629521/main.go:9: use of package str without selector
```

Trying

```
results := make(map[str.string]int)
```

now fails with

```
tmp/sandbox424441423/main.go:9: cannot refer to unexported name strings.string
tmp/sandbox424441423/main.go:9: undefined: strings.string
```

Comment: Besides `string` being a builtin type, don't rename imports unless you have to. There's no reason to try an use `str` instead of `strings`, when everyone else knows the package by the name `strings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"string" is a builtin. You don't need to do strings.string:

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#string